# Woocommerce product feed default pricing issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `woocommerce` and `woocommerce product feed` plugin. I have most of my products as variable, now few of the variable products are set to a default variation with a higher price, but the gpf plugin sends the lowest price variation to google.

Due to this google has sent me a preemptive disapproval warning due to price mismatch. Is there any way that the gpf create feed on the basis of default variation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried the option " Hide this product from the feed" but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please ask plugin support… StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support.

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately woocommerce doesn't provide customization under it support policy.

Comment: This is a missing feature that you are asking in a third party plugin…
 StackOverFlow doesn't provide either free coding or customizations… So you should better ask the plugin authors or hire a developer to do it for you.

Comment: Try this free [woocommerce product feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) plugin